# high cardinality in promethues for same url

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

We are calling a 3rd party api   **/api/{code}/authvalue**. Now each time we are calling this api we are getting micrometer is treating each call diffrenet as **{code}** which is different for each call.

we are using default micrometer of springboot of actuators.

Is there any way we can customize it?

```
/api/1234/authvalue
/api/4321/authvalue
/api/2324/authvalue
```

to treated as **/api/xxxx/authvalue** so that Prometheus can club all these metrics into one.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you are using a restTemplate to call the 3rd party api and you group on prometheus on the metric http.client.requests on the tag URI

It's mean that if you use

```
restTemplate.getForObject("/api/{code}/authvalue", ObjectReturn.class, Map.of("code","123456"));
```

The tag uri on your metric will be always *"/api/{code}/authvalue"* and you will be able to group it by "/api/{code}/authvalue".

Mostly the same for Webclient.

But anyway if you are using spring boot 3.0.X and you want to customise the metric you can still use ObservationRestTemplateCustomizer and ObservationWebClientCustomizer.

You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.http-clients)